# Merge/Combine two select statements into one

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got the following MySQL statement that has a couple of select statements of which one does a select for all the results returned by another select. Just wondering if it can be combined into one by any chance. Eg. Like a triple join.

```
select networks.name as network_name, installations.name as installation_name
from network_installations

join installations on installations.id = network_installations.installation_id

join networks on networks.id = network_installations.network_id

where network_installations.network_id in (
    select network_installations.network_id
    from network_installations 
    where network_installations.installation_id = 1
);
```

Note. I've done sql queries but this is my first experience with sql joins.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Without trying I wouldn't have reached so far. Initially I stored the select result in a PHP array and did a foreach to first the other query and appended the results. Then I modified it to the above one and now I'm trying to merge both. All of my merge queries so far have failed. That's the reason I made a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases for table network_installations:

```
select networks.name as network_name, installations.name as installation_name
from network_installations ni1
join installations on installations.id = ni1.installation_id
join networks on networks.id = ni1.network_id
join network_installations ni2 on ni2.network_id = ni1.network_id
where ni2.installation_id = 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a loads.  @mnv